# How to use a value as a parameter to target function

Tags: scala, functional-programming, apply

I realize this might be answered somewhere but I lack the correct terms to even search for it.
How can I keep composing functions together if at a certain point in the flow I require to use the current result as a parameter to a function?

Imagine this simple situation:

```
Seq(1, 2, 3).map(_ * 2)
            .map(doSomethingElseToEachValue(_))
            .useAsParameterIn(functionThatTakesTheWholeSequence(_))
```

Of course, it can be simply done by either assigning the intermediate result to a val and use that:

```
val intermeditateSeq = Seq(1, 2, 3)
    .map(_ * 2)
    .map(doSomethingElseToEachValue(_))
functionThatTakesTheWholeSequence(intermediateSeq)
```

Or by wrapping the function around the whole thing, but it makes for very poor readability as the execution flow goes back and forth as you read it.
It also gets a mangled mess if you have multiple of these operations inter-weaved.

How can I keep a left to right, top down logical flow when I need to use the whole object as a parameter and not just map over its contents?

Comment: The way you are doing it is just fine. There is no other way to do it  other than the ones you already described

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are ways to do it. At the very least you should be able to bring in an implicit that internally does f(a). However, sometimes I would like to keep the readability even in situations where performance is a concern, so It is desirable to avoid excessive boxing if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing you can do is just match:

```
Seq(1, 2, 3)
  .map(_ * 2)
  .map(doSomethingElseToEachValue) match {
      case xs => functionThatTakesTheWholeSequence(xs)
  }
```

Scala 2.13 brings also a new better possibility with [pipe](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/util/ChainingOps.html#pipe[B](f:A=%3EB):B):

```
Seq(1, 2, 3)
  .map(_ * 2)
  .map(doSomethingElseToEachValue)
  .pipe(functionThatTakesTheWholeSequence)
```

Actually writing *pipe* is pretty straightforward, so if you cannot use *2.13* but you want to use *pipe*, just copy extension function from [2.13 source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.0-RC1/src/library/scala/util/ChainingOps.scala#L22):

```
implicit class ChainingOps[A](private val self: A) extends AnyVal {
   def pipe[B](f: A => B): B = f(self)
}
```

Comment: Something like pipe is exactly what I was looking for, thanks.
I personally find it strange that something like this is only being added now.

Comment: @H4uZ I don't know either ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

if you only wanna do this kind of operations in `Seq[Int]` you can create an implicit class.

```
implicit class daClazz(list: Seq[Int]){
  def useAsParameterIn()= {
    //do stuff here
  }
}
```